# JSP , mysql & JDBC connection

Tags: java, html, mysql, jdbc

I have been making registration page using the code I once used in my project that worked 100% correctly, however I am getting errors  this time. I have added all libraries and jars
[image]

Still I keep getting errors like
[image]

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>CodeGyan - Learn Programming Online</title>
<link rel="icon" href="images/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">

</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%
String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastname=request.getParameter("lastname");
String username=request.getParameter("username");
session.putValue("username",username);
String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");
String email_id=request.getParameter("email_id");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/codegyan", "CinthiyaSingh", "Cinthiya@098");
//selecting username from users table
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select *from users where username=?");
ps.setString(1, username);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("select *from users where email_id=?");
ps1.setString(1, email_id);
ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
//if true
if (rs.next()) {
 //sending error message on Register page
 request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "Already Existing Username, Please Try Again With a Unique Username! ");
 request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp").forward(request, response);


 
}
else if(rs1.next()){
        request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "Already Existing Email, Please Try Again With Valid Email-ID! ");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp").forward(request, response);
} 
else {
 //If not exist performing insert 
 PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?)");
 //setting value for "?"
 ps2.setString(1, username);
 ps2.setString(2, pwd);
 ps2.setString(3, firstname);
 ps2.setString(4, lastname);
 ps2.setString(5, email_id);
 int i = ps2.executeUpdate();
 //if updated successfully
 if (i > 0) {
  //redirect
    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "Registered Successfully! Please Login to Fill The Form ");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
 }  
//close connection
con.close();
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a page (jsp) page where I have the form. The name of that page is Register.jsp. I have followed the method of build path to add jars still nothing changed.

Comment: Always [search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=classnotfoundexception+com.mysql.jdbc.Driver+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=osx&ia=web) thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that you are missing a dependency.
Try adding this to your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.26</version>
</dependency>
```

Tell me in the comments if this works for you or we need to debug further ?

Comment: Why am I unable to edit in pom.xml?

Comment: You are probably looking at the effective pom.xml in eclipse IDE. Just open the pom.xml file in a simple text editor and add this dependency there.

Comment: Good answer, except that answering [an obvious duplicate](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=classnotfoundexception+com.mysql.jdbc.Driver+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=osx&ia=web) is not helpful to the mission of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Basil What's the proper way to handle duplicates ?

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich Depending on your reputation, you can either flag to close as a duplicate (minimum reputation: 15), or vote to close as a duplicate (minimum reputation: 3000).